# How Do I Update Two Models in Rails Simultaneously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models, matching

Let's say I have an app that matches two People against each other, kind of like "hot or not."

I have my matchup view pulling random users out of the database and matching them up against each other. When a user votes for one of the people I would like to increase their `:wins` and `:matches_played` by 1 but I would also like to increase the losers `:matches_played` by 1 so that I can calculate rankings.

Is there is a way to use a form for each person to accomplish this or do I need a model in between, something like Match that has two columns for the winner and loser, and if so how would this work.

Comment: I'd separate this information into a `match` table and do some SQL to calculate what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it only using a **People** model (the "easy" way):

- Pro's: It's easy
- Con's: It's easy for people to inflate their "wins" by forging the form's parameters using Firebug or Chrome's Inspection tool

Assuming you have these routes:

```
new_person  GET     /people/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"people"}
edit_person GET     /people/:id/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"people"}
person      GET     /people/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"people"}
            PUT     /people/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"people"}
            DELETE  /people/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"people"}
```

HAML Version of the view code:

```
- # Person A form
= form_tag(person_path(@personA, :loser_id => @personB), :method => :put) do
  = submit_tag "Vote for Person A"

- # Person B form
= form_tag(person_path(@personB, :loser_id => @personA), :method => :put) do
  = submit_tag "Vote for Person B"
```

ERB Version:

```
<%# Person A form %>
<% form_tag(person_path(@personA, :loser_id => @personB), :method => :put) do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Vote for Person A" %>
<% end %>

<%# Person B form %>
<% form_tag(person_path(@personB, :loser_id => @personA), :method => :put) do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Vote for Person B" %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller for the `update` action you could do:

```
def update
  People.transaction do
    winner = People.find(params[:id])
    loser = People.find(params[:loser_id])

    # Increment the winner
    winner.increment! :matches_played
    winner.increment! :wins

    # Increment the loser
    loser.increment! :matches_played
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to new_match_path }
  end
end
```

As someone pointed out in the comments, you should probably wrap this in what is called a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) so that it's only permanently in the database if everything within the transaction saves successfully.

---

Even though I'm showing you the method above, I'd still recommend using a `Match` model.  Ultimately, using that extra model will help you validate the following things so people can't game your system.

- User's can only vote once per match
- User can't vote on a match involving them
- User can't forge a form to inflate their wins
- Separate's concerns as far as Models go and keeps your data more organized and clear for analytics purposes

Yes, this all requires more work (which is why I'm not showing code for it), but it may be something you want to do if you're concerned about any of the above.

Comment: Thanks so much, very thorough and clear answer. Quick question though, I do have those routes set up(which I believe come from resources :people), does that mean submitting a form with the :method => :put automatically uses the update action?

Comment: And out of curiosity, how would you convert the haml above to erb? Would it be a form_for with the same arguments and a hidden field? Not really sure how it should look.

Comment: Hey Zach, sorry for the late reply.  You are correct about the `:put` method.  If you look on the list of routes, the two bottom ones don't have a path helper name by them, so that means they use the path helper name above (which is `person` and then you append `_path` onto the end for the path helper... if you wanted the URL, you would append `_url`)

Comment: To convert it to ERB, you'd use the exact same code, you'd just surround it with the ERB tags `<% %>` and add a little extra code.  View the updated answer for ERB code.

Comment: Just as some extra info, here are some good RoR guides to start learning with: http://guides.rubyonrails.org and http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book and http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/CoursePage.php?course=WebApplications

Answer (score 0):

You should write your form submission to submit both user ids to your controller, with an indication of the winning user. Then you can operate on both and save them to the db.

```
winner = People.find(params[:winner_id])
loser  = People.find(params[:loser_id])
winner.matches_played += 1
winner.wins += 1
loser.matches_played += 1
winner.save!
loser.save!
```

Comment: What would I put in my views to make those params available in the controller?